# Android SimpleFTP Upload FatalException

Tags: java, android, ftp, fatal-error, ftp-client

I am slowly teaching myself Android and Java, I have this code which is submitting a file via FTP to a server/nas. Everything up to this point works great, except the submission. Once the button is clicked, I get an error, and force close. I can access the ftp console via cmd, FileZilla, or TinyFtp. So, I don't think it is that. I have imported the SimpleFTP library. Any help, whether direct code fix or just telling me what I did wrong and I'll find it, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
public class LegendsSubmitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_legends_submit);

    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

                // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
                //real info is there in code
                ftp.connect("xx", 21, "xx", "xx");

                // Set binary mode.
                ftp.bin();

                // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
                ftp.cwd("home/upload/");

                // Upload some files.
                ftp.stor(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Car/" + "EstimateFiles.zip"));
                //ftp.stor(new File("comicbot-latest.png"));

                // You can also upload from an InputStream, e.g.
                //ftp.stor(new FileInputStream(new File("test.png")), "test.png");
                // ftp.stor(someSocket.getInputStream(), "blah.dat");

                // Quit from the FTP server.
                ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Jibble.
                System.err.println("You done effed up" + e.getMessage());
            }


        }
    });

 }
}
```

Here is a log:

```
10-13 10:59:38.521 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.gabeogan.damageestimator, PID: 28069
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP.connect(SimpleFTP.java:68)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.gabeogan.damageestimator.LegendsSubmitActivity$1.onClick(LegendsSubmitActivity.java:34)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
10-13 10:59:38.581 28069-28069/com.gabeogan.damageestimator E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException clearly said that you are doing the network operation inside the Main thread. Do not touch the main thread of long operation. In addition you also write the code in onCreate Method this is what the activity is being created first time.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar Thank you, that clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) relates to the fact that a single thread that handles the UI (user interface), is now blocked waiting for a network result (tha may, for instance, fail)....

This behavior is not allowed in the device, and then the program is closed to allow users to continue using the device.

Check for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as a way to handle the issue.